# How to fix 'Static HTML elements with event handlers require a role.'?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, styled-components, prettier

My reactjs styledcomponent contains this code:

```
<a styling="link" onClick={() => this.gotoLink()}>
  <SomeComponent /> 
</a>
```

This works fine but the eslint is complaining:

```
Static HTML elements with event handlers require a role.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you try adding the `role=button` to the anchor tag

Answer (score 53, accepted):

you need to add a role props in your a tag to avoid this warning, for example a button

```
<a role = "button" styling="link" onClick={() => this.gotoLink()}>
  <SomeComponent /> 
</a>
```

I guess it is because the HREF props is missing in your anchor tag (not sure)

Comment: You may also need to add tabIndex='0' to avoid "'button' interactive role must be focusable"

Comment: for me somehow  tabIndex='0' was not working and  tabIndex={0} was working

Answer (score 25):

In my case, I used `aria-hidden="true"`, then I was able to commit.

Before:

```
<i className="pwdicon" onClick={togglePasswordVisiblity} >
```

After I updated with aria-hidden:

```
<i className="pwdicon" onClick={togglePasswordVisiblity} aria-hidden="true" >
```

My problem was resolved.

Reference Link : https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/click-events-have-key-events.md

Answer (score 8):

The earlier answers do give specific examples, what I was missing is a **list** of `roles`.
If someone is looking for other roles, a *partial* list is listed [here](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-static-element-interactions.md).
An example of a missing `role` is `tab` which I needed.

---

Edit: per the comment request, my personal error was solved by adding `role`, but I was missing a list of allowed roles, see above for a partial list and a more complete (or possibly complete) list [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions), thanks to the comment by [Caiof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8924092/caiof).

Comment: Please edit to include exact code to solve the OP's problem, in addition to the useful info you have added. As is, this is not a stand alone answer, but a Comment to another post. Indeed, some answers provided do not even use the `role` property, so without context, it may not even universally apply. For reference, the help section, linked at the top of every page, does indicate that *exact coded necessary* to solve the OP's issue must be *embedded* in Answers, whenever possible. Alternatively, post as a Comment to one or more posts. Links like this can be valuable as Comments.

Comment: A more complete list of roles: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the role explicitly. So, try the next code:

```
<a role="button" styling="link" onClick={this.gotoLink}>
  <SomeComponent /> 
</a>
```

Also, as you can see I've modified the `onClick` handler by replacing arrow function on regular declaration. It would reduce annoying and expensive calculations.

Answer (score 3):

just add  aria-hidden to it

```js
<a aria-hidden styling="link" onClick={() => this.gotoLink()}>
  <SomeComponent /> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add the 'aria-hidden' attribute, like this:

```html
<div onClick={handleClickCollectionCard} aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add 'aria-hidden' attribute to the element.
For example, I was working with `<span>` tag so I did the following:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => showDialog()}>Click here</span>
```

And, it worked fine!